# Cypehr Query with WHERE... AND is not working through python embedded binding

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j, cypher

I am working on a prototype where I have stored all my movie details stored on neo4j. I am using python as my programming language.

Now, I want to find out which movies I have rated at a specific level (let's say 10.0). For this I have written the following Cypher query:

```
START me=node(1) 
MATCH me-[r:likes]-> movies 
WHERE has(r.Ratings) and r.Ratings = '10.0' 
RETURN movies
```

This works fine on the neo4j webadmin. However, when I run the same using python :

```
myMovies = db.query("START me=node({id}) MATCH me-[r:likes]-> movies WHERE has(r.Ratings) and r.Ratings = '10.0' RETURN movies",id=user["nodeID"])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GraphTest.py", line 228, in <module>
    test.findTaste("Paritosh Kumar")
  File "GraphTest.py", line 31, in findTaste
    taste = self.BuildTasteForUser(user)
  File "GraphTest.py", line 52, in BuildTasteForUser
    myMovies = db.query("START me=node({id}) MATCH me-[r:likes]-> movies WHERE has(r.Ratings) and r.Ratings = '10.0' RETURN movies",id=user["nodeID"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 155, in query
    return self._cypher_engine.execute(query, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4j/cypher.py", line 31, in execute
    return ExecutionResult(self._engine.execute(query,to_java(params)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4j/_backend.py", line 156, in decorator
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
jpype._jexception.CypherExceptionPyRaisable: unknown function
"START me=node({id}) MATCH me-[r:likes]-> movies WHERE has(r.Ratings) and r.Ratings = '10.0' RETURN movies"
```

I am new to Cypher and neo4j as such and am not sure why this is happening. Can someone please help me out?

Regds,
Paritosh

Comment: I am using neo4j 1.8.1

Comment: could you try it with the node(1) like this? `START me=node({id}) MATCH me-[r:likes]-> movies WHERE has(r.Ratings) and r.Ratings = '10.0' RETURN movies",id=1)` whether you still got the same error

Comment: Is this failing just in Python or even in the console or neo4j-shell?

Comment: Peter... this is failing in python. Its working with webadmin, I am not sure about the neo4j-shell.

Answer (score 0):

Use the !([15.11.9](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html)) operator:

```
START me=node(1) 
MATCH me-[r:likes]-> movies 
WHERE r.Ratings! = '10.0' 
RETURN movies
```

Comment: actually i just read in the docu that has() should be valid, but for some reason it is not working for me in that context.

Comment: I tried this first... but it didn't work and that's why I had to go for the round about method (using has()) :( .. anyways, the error I get is : 
jpype._jexception.CypherExceptionPyRaisable: expected return clause
"START me=node({id}) MATCH me-[r:likes]-> movies WHERE r.Ratings! ='10.0' RETURN movies"
                                                                ^